# Почему не отрабатывает плавный скролл

Tags: javascript, браузер, кроссбраузерность

Есть простой код. Он должен реализовать плавный скролл на веб-странице.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const footer = document.querySelector('footer');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.scroll( {
    top: footer.offsetTop,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
});
```

На компьютере в котором я работаю установлены следующие браузеры: chrome, edge, opera, firefox, yandex.
Когда я проверяю это в firefox плавный скролл работает как положено. Но в chrome, edge, opera и yandex это происходит резко, то есть функция не отрабатывает.
Версии браузеров у меня установлены последние.

Если вы проверите мой код здесь (https://codepen.io/Vagif/pen/BazGXmw?editors=1010) то скорее всего у вас проблем не возникнет.
Пробовал взять полифил отсюда (http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/) такая же история. Скорее всего проблема не в коде а у меня локально, подскажите куда рыть.

Comment: не отрабатывает именно код который приведен в вопросе? или вокруг него еще что-то есть? разметка, другой код?

Comment: код на codepen - тоже не работает?

Comment: код на codepen - у меня не работает. В этом то и проблема.

Comment: Какая версия браузера и os? установлены какие-либо расширения?

Comment: версия хром  93.0.4577.82  windows 10 версия 21H1 (сборка OC 19043.1165)  расширения хром 
AdBlock   PerfectPixel by WellDoneCode (pixel perfect)    WAVE Evaluation Too     доступ к Рутрекеру  
  Темная тема для ВК | Dark the

Comment: Попробуй либо отключить расширения все, либо в приватном режиме, там обычно расширения отключены по умолчанию

Comment: Это не лечит. В firefox норм. в остальных не работает. С моб. захожу тоже норм.  Непонятно. Но дело не должно быть в расширениях. Некоторые браузеры у меня установлены только для теста кроссбраузерности и никаких расширений я на них не навешивал, тем не менее там такая же беда со скроллом(кроме firefox).

Comment: _Это не лечит_ - ты пробовал?

Comment: ты пробовал?    Да пробовал, конечно.

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть ошибки в консоли браузера при клике

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть ошибки в консоли браузера при клике --- отсутствуют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в пункте smooth-scrolling в настройках браузера(я сейчас говорю конкретно про хром) Эта функция по умолчанию почему-то выключена(у меня) и более того скрыта.
Если у кого-то схожая проблема, включить функцию можно так:

-Запускаем веб-обозреватель, вводим в адресную строку текст chrome://flags/ и жмем на кнопку .
-В поле поиска вставляем #smooth-scrolling.
-Сменяем значение для данного параметра на Enabled.
-Затем перезапускаем браузер. Проще всего это сделать, нажав на кнопку Relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать другой метод:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Ваше демо к слову у меня работает, если метод выше не поможет, то делайте чистый браузер, если заработает, то очевидно, что проблема либо в расширениях, либо в кэше.

Comment: [_Window.scroll() is effectively the same as this method._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Comment: @Grundy да, одно и то же, это плод отсутствия стандарта и хром поддерживает оба, но мы не знаем что происходит у тс, какой вообще версии у него хром и что еще он не договаривает. В любом случае от теста не убудет.

Comment: Версия хрома указана в комментарии _версия хром 93.0.4577.82 windows 10 версия 21H1 (сборка OC 19043.1165)_